Does Bhagavad Gita 18.66 suggest that the Gita was spoken by Brahman and not the personal deity Krishna?
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/66

सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज | अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुच: || 66||


sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaṁ śharaṇaṁ vraja ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣhayiṣhyāmi mā śhuchaḥ


Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto Me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

the key word is vraja
https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=vraj

Root Word  IAST    Meaning Monier Williams Page    Class
√व्रज् vraj    going / gati    347/3   Cl.1


√व्रज् vraj    trimming, preparing / mārga-saṃskāra    812/2, 1120/2   Cl.10


√व्रज् vraj    going / gati    347/3   Cl.10

Krishan, standing in front of Arjuna would have said come to take refuge in me and not go to take refuge in me.
Sharanagati means "coming to surrender" not "going to surrender".
EDIT:  not the same as asking a general question whether Krishna was connected to Brahman - asking about evidence within Bhagavad Gita itself.

This question is similar to: Is there any reference that Krishna was connected to Brahman while speaking Gita?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In your edit, you say that you are asking for evidence within the Gita. But you accepted an answer that quotes from outside the Gita. Of course, it is your prerogative what answer you want to accept, but then, this question looks like a duplicate. @SK (I have not marked it duplicate, so far). Can you please explain better what you are looking for, so that we can better try to give you an answer?

Krishna has said in Anu Gita how he spoke the Gita. He was in a yogic state when he spoke the Bhagavad Gita. Krishna was not in a normal consciousness state when he spoke.

Having been thus addressed, the greatly energetic Krishna, supreme
among eloquent ones, embraced Phalguna and replied in these words, "I
made you listen to something that is eternal and secret. O Partha!
That was about the nature of eternal dharma for all the worlds. I am
greatly displeased that you have ignorantly not grasped what I told
you. O Pandava! It is evident that you have not been faithful, or your
intelligence is not adequate. That dharma is sufficient to obtain the
state of the brahman. However, I am incapable of telling you
everything in detail again. I immersed myself in yoga and told you
about the supreme brahman. But I will tell you about an ancient
history with the same purport. Using that, if you use your
intelligence, you will reach the ultimate destination, O best among
those who uphold dharma! ...

Mahabharata, Ashvamedhika Parva, Chapter 1851 (16) translated by Bibek Debroy

Don't why this is getting downvoted. There are just quotes here, without any interpretation or bias

A look at the Monier williams dictionary for the word vraj (व्रज्) can clarify things. While the main meaning of व्रज् is "to go", it can also be used differently as indicated below, underlined in blue.

From the above usage given, vraj can be used with शरणम् and accusative, indicating ‘to take refuge with’ someone. So, here vraj simply means "take", as the Gita uses
शरणं व्रज.
This is also easily seen from the translations by Swami Gambhirananda and Swami Sivananda in gitasupersite.

English Translation By Swami Gambirananda


18.66 Abandoning all forms of rites and duties, take refuge in Me alone. I shall free you from all sins. (Therefore) do not grieve.


English Translation By Swami Sivananda


18.66 Abandoning all duties, take refuge in Me alone: I will liberate thee from all sins; grieve not.



conservative, orthodox translatiors assume a personal deity was standing next to Arjuna to preach the Gita to him..  But it is more than clear that the Gita has nothing to do with personal deities and is coming from Brahman and in all likelihood wasn't even preached on the battlefield @estimator

Monier-Williams dictionary is written by westerners. Not conservative or orthodox persons. @SK

Hindus minds are saturated with images of Krishna peaching the gita and Arjuna kneeling before him.  The primary sense is "to go".  An average Kshatriya wouldn't have understood one pct of the philosophical theories Krishna was expounding.  There was no Krishana or Arjuna when the Gita was composed (as coming from Brahman) and has been interpolated onto Krishna and Arjuna in the battlefield @estimator  very little of the Gita was necessary to teach a kshatriya not to go softhearted and follow his varnadharma.

The topic of the question is about the word vraj and I believed I addressed it to the best of my abilities using a neutral source like MW. @SK  Have a good day!

@SK not to go offtopic but there's no reason to believe that, unless you've just decided it somehow got interpolated into the Jaya, which is the Core of the MBH.

It means Krishna is the supreme God and is the ultimate destination of all

As the rainwater goes to the ocean, the followers of Siva, the Sun,
Ganesa, Visnu, so also the worshippers of Sakti come to me only.


Chapter 88, Uttara Khanda, Padma Purana.


The subject of all ancient knowledge is Narayana. The liberation is to
reach Narayana. The last destination (of all beings) is Narayana. All
dharmas are directed towards Narayana.

Chapter 33, Bhavishya Parva, Harivamsa.

not an answer, the word "Narayana" does not occur in the Bhagavad Gita. @gokulrenjith

@S K - So what ? It's the name of Lord Krishna. Gita is not an isolated text.

here is more proof that the speaker of the Gita was not standing next to Arjuna:
https://haricharanam.blogspot.com/2013/02/bhagavad-gita-chapter-9-rajavidya_21.html

Bhagavad Gita Chapter 9 - Rajavidya Rajaguhya Yoga - Sloka 25


Yanti deva vratah devan pitrun yanti pitru vratah I


Bhutani yanti bhutejyah yanti matd yajinah api mam II sloka 25


यान्ति देव व्रताः देवान् पितृन् यान्ति पितृव्रुताः I


भूतानी यान्ति भूतेज्याः यान्ति मद्याजिनः अपि मां  I I  श्लोक 25


Votaries of the devas go to the devas; the votaries of the pitrus go to the >pitrus; to the bhutas go to the bhuta worshippers; my votaries come to me.

Sanskrit "yA" just means "go" but of course has a gazillion fanciful "meanings" like any number of Sanskrit words. Maybe there is a fanciful translation that says 'yA' means "come" also.  This translator has used poetic license to translate the last "yA" as "come".
https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=yA&dir=au
याति{या}                  Go
आयाति{आ- या}            Arrive
even present-day Hindi has
आयात निर्यात = IMPORT-EXPORT
Krishna could have easily said "AyAnti" for those who come unto him - but he says "yAnti" the same as the others - which means the speaker of the Gita is as remote from Arjuna as the pitrus or Devas or Bhutas.

Maybe, this can be asked as a separate question?
